# Changing my web browser in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: configuration, netbeans-6.9

I have Netbeans 6.9.1 and I want to change the default browser to Chrome. I have seen a thread that says for Netbeans 6.5, it can be configured from `Tools > Options > General` but the problem is I can't find Options in my Tools tab because I am not using that version. Anyone know how to do this with Netbeans 6.9.1?

Answer (score 23):

In the file `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\etc\netbeans.conf`, add the following line to the `netbeans_default_options` properties:

```
-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.extbrowser.UseDesktopBrowse=true
```

Then set Chrome as the default browser.

---

**Alternative method (tried this with Netbeans 7.1):**

Open `Tools > Options` and you should see this:

[image: Netbeans Options Dialog]

Click the edit button. Then click on the add button. A new browser named "External Browser" will be shown. You can rename it to Chrome, then change the "Process" field to a path like this:

> C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (on
>   my Windows 7)

In your case, you can right click on the Chrome icon and select the properties option (windows) and see where is the target path.

Comment: Yes, i've just tried and was successful. I expanded my answer above

Answer (score 4):

In case someone came across the same problem for Netbeans 8.2:
it is under

Run> Set Project Browser > Chrome

[image]

(You can choose other browsers of course!)

Answer (score 0):

nope cannot change this....the edit menu for a custom browser does not respond...u have to create a custom firefox.exe thats starts up the required browser.exe.