# Tomcat is opening Internet Explorer when it is deployed. How can I change this?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am using Netbeans and Tomcat for my app. My default browser is Chrome, but when I deploy the app on Tomcat it is opening IE, how can I change this?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't open anything. NetBeans is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing my web browser on netbans 6.9.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446982/changing-my-web-browser-on-netbans-6-9-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With NetBeans Open:

1. Open Tools/Options
2. Select the General tab if it isn't already
3. Select either Chrome or `<Default System Browser>` (if you'd always like to use the system default).