# How to set Google Chrome as default browser in NetBeans?

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, browser

Chrome executable is located in user's profile folder. I don't want to use explicit username in setup.

Unfortunately, neither

`C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

nor

`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

from this answer [changing my web browser on netbans 6.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446982/changing-my-web-browser-on-netbans-6-9-1) worked for me.

NetBeans says "Cannot create process. Check the browser configuration".

Explicit username works.

Answer (score 12):

You can follow these steps as mentioned [here](http://www.santhoshreddymandadi.com/java/change-default-browser-with-netbeans-ide.html), it worked for me (I restarted my NetBeans after changing web browser):

1. From "Tools" menu, select "Options". IDE will open options dialog box as displayed below
2. Choose the browser from "Web browser" drop down. All the browsers installed on your machine will appear on this drop down. The default option is "Default system browser"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.

In addition, consider stating the NetBeans version and the operating system you are using.