# Add a new web browser (Vivaldi) to NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, browser, vivaldi

I've installed a new web browser to my computer. It's called [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com) and I want to test all of its functionalities, the ones linked to web development, inclusive.

How can I add this new browser to Netbeans 8.0.1 and make it default?

Also, could someone with a reputation of 1,500+ add "Vivaldi" as a new tag?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Just find out. I defined Vivaldi as the default browser in the system and them executed my project. I followed the instructions in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446982/changing-my-web-browser-on-netbans-6-9-1